# Is there a flood of spam regarding koa recently?

Tags: discussion, spam, sock-puppets

Recently, I notice that there is quite a number of new questions regarding [koa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/koa). Most of the questions are just a dump of some code structure and ask no seeming question. They could be asking for "review", or posting "working solution"(not in self Q&A style); or some very vague question like "is it correct way to do ...?"

Here are some of the examples that I can gather:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72790789/build-ecommerce-system-using-koa
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72788002/what-is-the-right-way-to-create-routes-dao-api/72790616#72790616
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72790050/i-created-a-backend-project-using-koa-am-i-correct
4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72789968/i-am-having-cors-erros-when-connect-backend-to-the-frontend-i-use-axios-and-koa
5. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72790915/mern-stack-backend
6. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72789306/how-to-create-simple-crud-koa-with-react-frontend
7. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72791085/app-usebroutes-routes-referenceerror-broutes-is-not-defined-node-js-v18-4
8. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72791101/how-can-i-create-rest-api-in-koa-js
9. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72791319/my-code-is-not-working-properly-it-is-koa-how-can-i-resolve-this-problem
10. [Request Body is undefined in KOA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148087/request-body-is-undefined-in-koa/72791251#72791251)
11. [Request Body is undefined in KOA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148087/request-body-is-undefined-in-koa/72791294#72791294)

So is this a new kind of spam? How should I handle similar posts when I see them?

Comment: Short answer: yes, but not sure if it's spam or a sockpuppet ring.  There is also plagiarized content involved in some posts I've seen. Personally, I think it's a sockpuppet ring.  At any rate, please flag this stuff for moderator attention.  We're deleting it as quickly as we can, but it's a bit tricky to find it all.

Comment: @RyanM at the moment, [searching for the newest posts with 'koa' keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=koa&searchOn=3) will list all these posts from suspicious new accounts...

Comment: @RyanM So we should *not* use either the spam or rude/abusive flags, only use a custom flag?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Personally, I'm fine with red flags on these, if you're confident it's them and okay with a potential declined flag here and there.  I've been responding to confirmed cases by red-flag nuking all their posts.  My concern is that they may be incorrectly declined by moderators who don't recognize why they're being flagged.  I've asked the rest of the mod team for their thoughts.

Comment: For the custom flags, I've been searching for "koa" in the queue to find them all, so including that word is helpful.  So far I've deleted everything I could 100% confirm (which was the vast majority), but there are a couple that may need a little more analysis to be certain.

Comment: For the record, "spam" is strictly speaking not correct for posts which don't promote a product or service (or religion, mathematical proof, membership in an occult organization, etc etc etc); plain old vandalism, trolling, posting junk, etc should probably get the "rude/abusive" flag (if you are confident enough that that's what it is - it's obviously often tricky to divine the author's intent and/or level of confusion).

Comment: Many of the recent [tag:koa] posts are certainly closable as very low quality / unclear etc regardless of any sockpuppet ring or conspiracy.